# MemoryCache does not appear to be caching

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I am trying to implement caching in one of our projects.

I have no experience with this part of the framework, so am likely doing something very wrong

Using code I found over at Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/generic-thread-safe-memorycache-manager-for-c) I came up with, more or less, the same - added the ability to add lists to the cache.

I have this (just showing the code i am using):

```
 private CacheItemPolicy _defaultCacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
        };


        public CacheUtil(string cacheName)
            : base(cacheName) { }


        public void Set(string cacheKey, Func<T> getData)
        {
            this.Set(cacheKey, getData(), _defaultCacheItemPolicy);
        }

        public bool TryGetAndSet(string cacheKey, Func<List<T>> getData, out List<T> returnData)
        {
            if (TryGet(cacheKey, out returnData))
            {
                return true;
            }
            returnData = getData();
            this.Set(cacheKey, returnData, _defaultCacheItemPolicy);
            return true;
        }

        public bool TryGet(string cacheKey, out List<T> returnItem)
        {
            returnItem = (List<T>)this[cacheKey];
            return returnItem != null;
        }
```

I can then call this by doing this:

```
public override List<T> GetAll()
{
    string keyName = typeof(T).ToString();
    List<T> t;
    _cache.TryGetAndSet(keyName, () => base.GetAll(), out t);
    return t;
}
```

`base.GetAll()` is a function in a repository class that fetches data, via EF.

If i call my `GetAll()` twice it sets the list into the cache again - `returnItem = (List<T>)this[cacheKey];` is coming up `null` every time.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are these EF context objects? If so, won't the class name be different?

Comment: base.GetAll() are EF DBSet objects, yes. though the keyname is the same - in this case it's "ProjectName.Data.Models.StatusType" - and that doesn't change.